# Can not delete meeting with exchange web services

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We have a problem deleting Appointments from Exchange using EWS.

We try to delete Appointments from Exchange like this

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
service.Credentials = CurrentUser; // NetworkCredential
service.Url = new Uri(WebserviceAddress);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

var appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, id);
deletedAppointment.Delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems, SendCancellationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

We get an exception with the message "Object cannot be deleted."

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException was
>   caught   Message=Object cannot be deleted.
>   Source=Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices   StackTrace:
>          at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponse.InternalThrowIfNecessary()
>          at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
>          at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalDeleteItems(IEnumerable`1
>   itemIds, DeleteMode deleteMode, Nullable`1 sendCancellationsMode,
>   Nullable`1 affectedTaskOccurrences, ServiceErrorHandling
>   errorHandling)
>          at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.DeleteItem(ItemId
>   itemId, DeleteMode deleteMode, Nullable`1 sendCancellationsMode,
>   Nullable`1 affectedTaskOccurrences)
>          at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalDelete(DeleteMode
>   deleteMode, Nullable`1 sendCancellationsMode, Nullable`1
>   affectedTaskOccurrences)
>          at
>   Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Appointment.Delete(DeleteMode
>   deleteMode, SendCancellationsMode sendCancellationsMode)
>          at
>   OurNameSpace.ExchangeCalendar.ViewCalendars.ExchangeMethods.DeleteMeeting(ItemId
>   id)   InnerException:

If we instead try to use cancel the meeting

```
deletedAppointment.CancelMeeting();
```

we get an exception with the message "User must be an organizer for CancelCalendarItem action." This makes me really confused, because when I inspect the `deletedAppointment` object my email address is set as the organizer.

We create our meetings like this

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
appointment.Subject = subject;
appointment.Body = body;
appointment.Start = start;
appointment.End = end;
appointment.Location = location;
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(location);
appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(requiredAttendees);
try
{
    appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
}
catch ...
```

`location` contains the name of a conference room mailbox.
if we pause a while (until the Appointment appears in Outlook) and call Delete on the same Appointment instance we used when we created the meeting the appointment is deleted successfully.

The code runs in a custom SharePoint 2010  WebPart. Not that I could think that it would make any difference, but who knows?

Why can't I delete the appointment?
How can I investigate further?
As far as I can see the code is mostly copy'n paste of an MSDN example.

**Edit**
When I copy a minimal example of the code to a Winform application the meeting is deleted correctly. Could there be any critical difference when running in the Sharepoint context?

**Edit 2**
`CurrentUser` is a user supplied username and password. The Exchange server is not on the same domain as SharePoint server.

**Edit 3**
If I open the appointment in outlook (with the same login as in the `CurrentUser` variable) I can cancel the appointment.

Comment: the sharepoint context changes permissions etc. - the identity the Exchange sees is different from the one it sees on your Winforms application... either impersoante the needed identity and/or use an administrative user explicitly for the connection to Exchange...

Comment: @Yahia, I guess I was not not clear enough that I supply user specific Exchange credentials in the `CurrentUser` variable and that the Exchange server is not on the same domain as the SharePoint server.

Comment: that alone won't do it - my explanation seems to be unclear... check this http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040511.htm and then impersonate the respective user before connecting to Exchange, then connect to Exchange the way you are already doing...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last we found out that the issue was outside the simplified example above.
The issue was that we used a "view only" account to fetch all the appointments in the calendar. We then tried to use that appointment id when we tried to delete the appointment using the `CurrentUser` credentials, but that ID was not valid in the context of the new user.
When we changed to retrieve the calendar items with `CurrentUser` instead of our view only account everything started to work.

Thanks anyway for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

The user performing the delete operation must have enough permissions to delete the Meetings from a specific resource/user's calender.

In case of SharePoint, the web part code will be run under the current logged on user (as visible from your code) however, current logged on user may not have enough rights to perform the operation on every Exchange object's calender. I would recommend setting up a dedicated Active Directory user who will perform the calls from the code and at the same time have full access to manipulate the calendar items of every Exchange Server's object (user or resource).

Here are some useful PowerShell scriptlets to set the permissions for the user and perform the deletion operation again.

```
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity MeetingRoom1@test.com:\Calendar -User Default -AccessRights Reviewer

Set-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity MeetingRoom2@test.com:\Calendar -User administrator@test.com  -AccessRights Owner
```

Good luck

Comment: Asking our Exchange administrator for an account with permission to mess up every calendar in the whole company is not an option.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the part with "every Exchange object's calender". If I create a meeting with my and a conference room account as attendees, am I not allowed with my account to remove the appointment from the conference room calendar or what? I guess I'm a bit lost about how Exchange allocate Appointments in different calendar when I create a meeting.